# How do I break my query result into smaller chunks

Tags: database

**Background**

I have a query that returns 140000+ results and I need to perform more calculations on the result before displaying them to the user. This has caused a huge wait time (left it to run for 1hr and 30 mins and it still wasn't finished).

**Problem**

The wait time is huge and needs to be reduced. I can happily load all the data (140000+ results) and run a lesser calculation. This is no use if I can't run the full calculation.

**Possible Solution**

I've thought about this and I think if I was able to limit the results returned (say 1000 results) I would be able to run the full calculation with no problems.

**Question**

Can I limit the amount of results back (say results 0-999) run my calculation on them and then load the next bit (results 1000-1999) and run the calc again?

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for the [Drupal Batch API](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/batch_example!batch_example.module/group/batch_example/7)

Comment: Depending on the exact process (querying external, data constantly being updated, etc.) it may also be a good candidate for Cron processes or [Ultimate Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.drupal.org/node/1848368

> Queries may also be restricted to a certain subset of the records
>   found. In general this is known as a "range query". In MySQL, this is
>   implemented using the LIMIT clause. To limit the range of a query, use
>   the range() method, which takes two arguments: the first specifies
>   offset and the second specifies limit
>
> In most cases we want "the first n records". To do that, pass 0 as the
>   first argument and n as the second.
>
> ```
> <?php
> // Limit the result to 10 records
> // where 0 is offset and 10 is limit
> $query->range(0, 10);
> ?>
> ```
>
> The following example will instruct the result set to start at the 6th
>   record found (the count starts at 0) rather than the first, and to
>   return only 10 records.
>
> ```
> <?php
> $query->range(5, 10);
> ?>
> ```
>
> Calling the range() method a second time will overwrite previous
>   values. Calling it with no parameters will remove all range
>   restrictions on the query.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for but i need some way for the user to pick the limits and offset. Can this be done when building a view?